# Find left function for an array

Tags: arrays, excel

I have a bunch of text in an Excel column like so:

```
      A    B
1   20/24   
2   1/3 
3   2/5
```

I would like to extract the numerators and the denominators, so I use the following function:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1)
```

and

```
=RIGHT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1)
```

sum these for all applicable cells and then concatenate the strings to display the resulting fraction.

However, I would like to do this for A1:A20. I can copy and paste the left and right functions twenty times, but this is inefficient. Is there a way to do this with arrays? I tried:

```
=CONCATENATE(SUM(LEFT(A1:A20,FIND("/",A1:A20)-1)),"/",SUM(RIGHT(A1:A20,FIND("/",A1:A20)-1)))
```

But that just returns A1 (20/24). The end result in this example should be 23/32. Any hints?

Comment: Find counts from the Left, so if you have `21/3` your right will return `/3` not `3`

Comment: That is strange - if I have a double digit number in the denominator, Find...-1 returns "xx", but if I have a one digit number in the denominator, Find...-1 returns "/x".

Comment: that is because `FIND` counts from the left not the right.  So in the case of `21/3` the `FIND` will always return `3` whether in the `LEFT` or the `RIGHT` so `3-1` equals 2.  The `RIGHT` Function wants the number of character from the right so the last two characters are `/3` .  If the number of digits between the two match then it works, but if they don't you will get erroneous information.

Comment: I see. So I was basically overriding my formula. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT and MID instead of SUM and RIGHT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(A1:A3,FIND("/",A1:A3)-1)) & "/" & SUMPRODUCT(--MID(A1:A3,FIND("/",A1:A3)+1,10))
```

[image]